# How to start audio drivers from Netbeans using java

Tags: java, audio, netbeans

I'm trying to make a Java application that would simulate sorting, sorting visualization and audibilization. There are many videos on YouTube that compare different sorts, and the idea is to make something like that.

I never implemented any code to play or generate sounds, so I found some help online, and the class that is used for creating sound looks like this:

```
public class Sound {

public static float SAMPLE_RATE = 8000f;

public static void sound(int hz, int msecs, double vol)
        throws LineUnavailableException {

    if (hz <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Frequency <= 0 hz");
    }

    if (msecs <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duration <= 0 msecs");
    }

    if (vol > 1.0 || vol < 0.0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Volume out of range 0.0- 1.0");
    }

    byte[] buf = new byte[(int) SAMPLE_RATE * msecs / 1000];

    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        double angle = i / (SAMPLE_RATE / hz) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
        buf[i] = (byte) (Math.sin(angle) * 127.0 * vol);
    }

    // shape the front and back 10ms of the wave form
    for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_RATE / 100.0 && i < buf.length / 2; i++) {
        buf[i] = (byte) (buf[i] * i / (SAMPLE_RATE / 100.0));
        buf[buf.length - 1 - i] = (byte) (buf[buf.length - 1 - i] * i / (SAMPLE_RATE / 100.0));
    }

    AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, 8, 1, true, false);
    SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
    sdl.open(af);
    sdl.start();
    sdl.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
    sdl.drain();
    sdl.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException {
    Sound.sound(600, 200, 0.9);
}
```

}

It works pretty fine, as well as the rest of the program, but there is one (for me) unexpected problem.
When I start the application, sounds that are played sound a bit strange, like some noises, not like a sine like expected. After a while, I realized that when I start application with any other application that uses sound running in background (like a song in winamp or a movie, whatever), the sound works good, just like it is expected to be. Those background songs or anything like that can be paused, it doesn't matter, just they have to opened in order for my application to work fine (I mean the sound, nothing else is a problem).

After some thinking, I guess that the other app running somehow starts some audio drivers or something like that, which was not done in my application (that's just my guess, it can be anything as far as I know).

I couldn't find any similar questions to this one online, maybe this is unusual, but I have no idea how to fix it. Any help will be appreciated. Have in mind that I'm not really familiar with sound manipulation.
And if it's important, I have Windows operating system and I use NetBeans IDE.

**Just some clarification:** I sure as hell have no idea what's going on here, but I'm also sure that it is as I said above. When I first start an app, the sound is not good (some humming instead of a clear sound that we would expect), later, whenever I start any application that uses sound (like a movie or an mp3 player) the sound is as expected. If I would pause that application (but leave it running, for example pause a song or a movie), the sounds in my app still work good, but if I close that 'sound consuming' background app, my app becomes like it used to be in the beginning, with some strange humming instead of a clear sound. I wouldn't write this if I didn't really see it happen; it definitely is strange, but it's happening and I would love to know why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, there's no "audio drivers" that need to be started. If your sounds are working, then the audio drivers are already functioning correctly.

Comment: You are probably right about the drivers, that's what I thought about, but like I said, I really don't know what's going on here. But if it's not that, what is it? What do you think is happening here?

Comment: Have you tried it on different hardware?

Comment: I did try on a different computer, if that's what you mean, on a laptop and a pc, both running Windows operating systems, although different versions. The same thing.